# ReactNative - Redux not immediately update

Tags: android, react-native, redux, components

I know this.setState is asynchronous.

But now, I use Redux and in reducer there is no this.setState. I can use callbacks for setState but in redux I don't know where to put the callbacks and how. In action? (no) in Reducer? in Component? in Container? in Store? (no).

I'm new to redux and reactnative, so I hope you understand my question.

My data is updating but with one step late.

exemple :

> tap: 'a',   state = ''
>
> tap: 'ab, state = 'a'
>
> tap: 'abc', state = 'ab'

In component, I call function like this :

```
let { myFunction1, myFunction2 } = this.props;
myFunction1();
```

So setting state works but I need to handle this late.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setState` for storing value `onChange`, once user done with the input you can call your reducer function to save value to your store. It will reduce the number of call to reducer function.

Example:

```
<TextInput
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.onNextPress()}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)}
/>
```

Use have `onChangeText(text)` to handle your `setState` and once submitted (or your event triggered), use another function to handle reducer call. In my example it is `onNextPress()`